# How to import data from multiple csv or text files into DatagridView using Visual Basic

Tags: datagridview

I am using Visual Basic and have limited programing knowledge. I have a text box that contains, lets say path of four txt or CSV files.  I want to import data of all these files into DataGridView.  I know how to import data of a single file but not sure how to import data from multiple files.  Can anyone help me by sharing code.

Answer (score 0):

I did answered for another Post, Re-load here for your information, hope can help

Noted: You need design your Datagridview Header Text match with your Header in CSV file, so more accurate when you load the files.

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\temp\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        For x = 0 To OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count
            Try
                Dim fName As String = ""
                fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x)
                Me.TextBox1.Text += fName

                Dim TextLine As String = ""

                Dim SplitLine() As String

                If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then

                    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)

                    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

                        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()

                        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "|")

                        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)

                    Loop

                Else

                    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
      MsgBox("Total files loaded = " & OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count)
    End If


End Sub
```